# Using loop function to set variable values for userform object

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have 60 text boxes in my userform and I would like a quick way to set their values.
I currently have:

```
  Dim TextB1_1, TextB1_2, TextB1_3, TextB1_4, TextB1_5, TextB1_6, TextB1_7, TextB1_8, TextB1_9, TextB1_10, TextB1_11, TextB1_12 As String
  Dim TextB2_1, TextB2_2, TextB2_3, TextB2_4, TextB2_5, TextB2_6, TextB2_7, TextB2_8, TextB2_9, TextB2_10, TextB2_11, TextB2_12 As String
  Dim TextB3_1, TextB3_2, TextB3_3, TextB3_4, TextB3_5, TextB3_6, TextB3_7, TextB3_8, TextB3_9, TextB3_10, TextB3_11, TextB3_12 As String
  Dim TextB4_1, TextB4_2, TextB4_3, TextB4_4, TextB4_5, TextB4_6, TextB4_7, TextB4_8, TextB4_9, TextB4_10, TextB4_11, TextB4_12 As String
  Dim TextB5_1, TextB5_2, TextB5_3, TextB5_4, TextB5_5, TextB5_6, TextB5_7, TextB5_8, TextB5_9, TextB5_10, TextB5_11, TextB5_12 As String
```

and to set the values I have:

```
TextB1_1 = Me.TextBox1_1.Text
TextB1_2 = Me.TextBox2_2.Text
TextB1_3 = Me.TextBox3_3.Text
TextB1_4 = Me.TextBox4_4.Text
TextB1_5 = Me.TextBox5_5.Text
TextB1_6 = Me.TextBox5_6.Text
TextB1_7 = Me.TextBox5_7.Text
TextB1_8 = Me.TextBox5_8.Text
TextB1_9 = Me.TextBox5_9.Text
TextB1_10 = Me.TextBox5_10.Text
TextB1_11 = Me.TextBox5_11.Text
TextB1_12 = Me.TextBox5_12.Text
```

I need to do the same for text box groups 2,3,4,5 and I though it would be easier to loop it and set the value to I for the group, however it does not work
ie

```
  For i = 1 To 5
    TextB&i&_1 = Me.TextBox1_1.Text
    TextB&i&_2 = Me.TextBox2_2.Text
    TextB&i&_3 = Me.TextBox3_3.Text
    TextB&i&_4 = Me.TextBox4_4.Text
    TextB&i&_5 = Me.TextBox5_5.Text
    TextB&i&_6 = Me.TextBox5_6.Text
    TextB&i&_7 = Me.TextBox5_7.Text
    TextB&i&_8 = Me.TextBox5_8.Text
    TextB&i&_9 = Me.TextBox5_9.Text
    TextB&i&_10 = Me.TextBox5_10.Text
    TextB&i&_11 = Me.TextBox5_11.Text
    TextB&i&_12 = Me.TextBox5_12.Text
  Next I
```

is it possible to loop as such, and if so, what do I need to do as I cant get this to work.
I have tried TextB1_&i too just in case that would simplify it, but that does not work either

Comment: Sixty text boxes sounds like a user’s nightmare, not giving meaningful names to variables sounds like a programmer’s nightmare. Whatever you are doing, it sounds like you need a collection of some Dictionary/Class/Map objects that would map the text boxes to the proper variables. Then loop through the collection.

Comment: 12 months x 5 years = 60, add in approval from the users and its all good. the issue is around how to shorten it, not why. Thanks for the heads up on dictionary/class/map. ill look into it

Comment: I was simply trying to suggest that it appears a `DataGridView` may be easier to implement. 12 columns with 5 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an array to store values and `Controls` property of Userform object to address textboxes by their name:

```
Dim TextB(1 To 5, 1 To 12) As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

With Me
    For i = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 12
            TextB(i, j) = .Controls("TextBox" & i & "_" & j).Text
        Next
    Next
End With
```

BTW, in VBA you have to explicitly declare all your `String` variables or they will be implicitly assumed as of `Variant` type
i.e.:

```
Dim TextB1_1, TextB1_2, TextB1_3, TextB1_4, TextB1_5, TextB1_6, TextB1_7, TextB1_8, TextB1_9, TextB1_10, TextB1_11, TextB1_12 As String
```

will lead to `TextB1_12` only being assumed as of `String` type, and all other ones as of `Variant` type.

while:

```
Dim TextB1_1 As String, TextB1_2 As String, TextB1_3 As String, TextB1_4 As String, TextB1_5 As String, TextB1_6 As String, TextB1_7 As String, TextB1_8 As String, TextB1_9 As String, TextB1_10 As String, TextB1_11 As String, TextB1_12 As String
```

will have all those variables being assumed as of `String` type

Comment: Quick note, this didn't work perectly for me, I had to make a tiny change so that it was:       'Year 1-5 Text boxes in an array
  For j = 1 To 5
    For k = 1 To 12
      TextB(j, k) = Controls("TextBox" & j & "_" & k)
    Next k
  Next j
I didn't have the array With Me, it was throwing an error when I did. Many thanks plus appreciate the tips on string/variant type